# Converting model from Caffe to ONNX

Tags: artificial-intelligence, caffe, onnx

I'd like to prototype with Javascript to detect the sky using a model trained on a [SkyFinder dataset](https://mypages.valdosta.edu/rpmihail/skyfinder/images/).

I tried to convert the Caffe model (prototxt and trained data above) published [here](https://mypages.valdosta.edu/rpmihail/skyfinder/) to the ONNX model using [MMdnn](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn).

Following command executed,

```
mmconvert --srcFramework caffe --inputWeight baseline.caffemodel --inputNetwork deploy.net --dstFramework onnx --outputModel baseline.onnx --inputShape 1 3 240 320
```

and this error came out

```
mmdnn.conversion.caffe.errors.ConversionError: Layer not found: label_0
```

Below is an excerpt from the first part of prototxt above. label_0 is connected to the dummy_data and convine_1 layers but does not appear to be defined anywhere.

```
name: "DeepBlueSky"
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 240
input_dim: 320 
layers {
  name: "dummy_data"
  type: DUMMY_DATA
  top: "label_0"
  dummy_data_param {
    data_filler {
      type: "constant"
      std: .5 
    }
    num: 1 
    channels: 1
    height: 240
    width: 320
  }
}

layers {
  name: "combine_1"
  type: CONCAT
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "label_0"
  top: "combine_1"
  concat_param {
    concat_dim: 1
  }
}
...
```

I'm a newbie, so it's possible I'm missing the basics, but if you've had a similar experience and have been able to resolve it, would you please share it?

Comment: I load the same model, failed too.